# How to get filtered documents firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `lots` that have many documents with are generated by firebase, those documents have `objects` in them with this form

```
//lot Document
   {
    attr1: {
        subattr1 : "some value",
        ...
    },
    attr2: {
        subattr1 : "some value",
        ...
    },
    user: {
        id : "some uid value xAsDFadfaWRDAFd",
        ...
    }
```

so in my firebase i have

```
//my collection
         xAsDFadfaWRDAFd-loot1
         xAsDFadfaWRDAFd-loot2
         xAsDFadfaWRDAFd-loot3
```

Right now i just want to be able to filter the collection by the `user id property`.

I have tried

```
firebase.collection('lots').where('user.id','==',uid).get().then(do Something if i find them);
```

but it do not find any, if i take the `.where('user.id','==',uid)` it retrieve all the docs from the collection, beside in the future i might want to filter by another property inside the docs, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

The code you didn't show, in the `then()` clause, is likely wrong. I set up the data in the console and ran the code successfully:

[image: Image of the Firebase Console with code on the left, and data on the right]

Here's the code:

```
db.collection("lots").where("user.id","==","ABCDE").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
```

If the code in the `then()` clause actually was correct, then consider checking that `user` and `id` are capitalized the same, and that `uid` contains the data you expect (one method to would be to hardcode a value you copy/paste from the document in the console.